# Is it OK to send a business letter in English/French-only to a foreign company?

Tags: cover-letter, language, correspondence

I am in France and I wish to send sponsorship request letters to various EU countries. If I use an automatic translator it will be unprofessional, and if I use a secretary, it can cost me hundreds of Euros for correspondance.

I have lived 10 years in the UK and write good English. Is it OK to send a sponsorship request letter in English and French only? What about English only? Is that judicious business etiquette?

Comment: Why not write it in French for France, Belgium, Luxembourg and in English for the remaining destinations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes this is OK.

If you don't speak a specific language, it makes no sense for you to send requests in that language.

From the company's perspective, if they receive your request in their native language they will assume that you can communicate in that language.  So unless you plan to go through the interview process with an automatic translator or secretary it is not a good idea.

You should send the request in the language you are most comfortable with.  If you are fluent in both English and French then you can send with either or both, depending on the company you send it to and which language would be most applicable to the specific company.